# Chrome ignores CSS print settings on portrait

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I am trying to control the layout of printing of a HTML element depending on portait or landscape. 
Here's what I put in CSS settings.

```
@media print and (orientation: landscape){
    /* Your code for portrait landscape */

    #reactView{ 
    /*chrome seems only look at this data*/
    height: 7in !important;
    }

@media print and (orientation: portrait){
    /* Your code for portrait landscape */

    #reactView{
    height: 10in !important;
    }
}
```

The settings work well on IE, Firefox. But on Chrome the the setting for portrait is not working. On portrait I got 7 inch too.

Is it a bug on Chrome? And is there a workaround? Thanks.

I am on Chrome 60, 64 bit.

Answer (score 2):

From my tests orientation:landscape works with IE and FF, but not Chrome. However Chrome works with min-width:600px. The way I combined them below works for all three browsers.

```
@media print {
    all
    @media (orientation:landscape) and (min-width:600px) {
        landscape
    }
}
@media screen {
    all
    @media (min-width:1006px) {
        landscape
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you give some detail about your adjustments?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting a page size in your css?

```
@page {
  size: letter portrait;
}
```

See https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-page/ and https://www.w3.org/TR/css-gcpm-3/

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This setting seems have no effect on IE and Firefox. On Chrome it restricts printing to portrait only mode. It's not what I really want.

Comment: You can change it to landscape or a4 or other paper size. Have you experimented with that?